# Save Video in RPPreviewController to a specific place instead saving to camera roll?

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

i´m screen recording with `ReplayKit` and when the delegate method `previewController(_:didFinishWithActivityTypes:)` is called when i click the save button, it automatically saves into the camera roll. How can i change that? I want to save the video somwhere on the filesystem on device. I searched all over google and in apple documentation, but i couldn´t find anything relating to that.

Comment: What specific place?

Comment: Somwhere on Filesystem to Access it later in a tableview

Answer (score 0):

If your app supports the app FILES, the replay kit can save file directly to the folder. For example VLC app has a folder in FILES. Otherwise you may need to implement an action extension to do the similar thing.

Comment: But how can I save it them directly to the files app for example ?

Comment: If VLC can get the saved mp4. so you also can build a similar extension.

Comment: The question is how can I access the save button to change the action and save directory

Comment: @SwiftNewling were you able to find the answer to your question: "how can I access the save button to change the action and save directory" ??

Answer (score 0):

use this API

```objectivec
- (void)startCaptureWithHandler:(nullable void (^)(CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer, RPSampleBufferType bufferType, NSError *_Nullable error))captureHandler completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSError *_Nullable error))completionHandler API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0), tvos(11.0), macos(11.0));
```

sample code:

```objectivec
-(void)startCapture {

    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

        [[RPScreenRecorder sharedRecorder]  startCaptureWithHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef  _Nonnull sampleBuffer, RPSampleBufferType bufferType, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            if (CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) && bufferType == RPSampleBufferTypeVideo) {
                NSLog(@"Recording started successfully.");
                //save using AVAssetWriter
            }
        } completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Recording started successfully.");
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Recording started error %@",error);
            }
        }];
    } else {
        // earlier versions issue
    }
}
```

Also: this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266113/replaykit-getting-the-video-without-going-to-rppreviewviewcontroller) may help u somehow

[AVAssetWriter Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriter?language=objc)